# Native Swift implementation of DEFLATE (unzip) algorithm

Tags: swift, zlib, swift2, compression

I have some data that has been compressed with the DEFLATE algorithm which I believe is basically just saying its zipped up.  I'm writing a swift app and I was interested in figuring out if there is a native pure swift (2.0) implementation of the unzip algorithm.

I need to implement this in a swift dynamic framework, and as such it would be preferable if i didn't have to use Objective-c code as that requires me to make an objc framework included by my swift framework etc.

I guess my question is either is there a native swift implementation or is there a way to use swift to call into zlib to do the unzipping natively?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a native swift implementation of zlib on github called [DeflateSwift](https://github.com/tidwall/DeflateSwift)

Comment: It is not being maintained at the time of writing and will not compile for Swift 5

Comment: Also it's not a native implementation of zlib. It is simply an interface to the actual zlib.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [Compression framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/Compression/index.html) introduced by Apple this summer.

I believe it can decompress any ZLIB compressed file (among other things) and should be pretty efficient at that.

Comment: But is there really anything new here as far as zlib is concerned? I mean, _zlib.h_ has always been right there and it still is.

Comment: @matt I believe this one was done by the Accelerate folks and they say ZLIB decompress is 1.6x faster than reference library (whatever it is). The API also looks different than zlib.h.More info: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=712

Comment: It looks like the framework is using zlib directly (so the performance will be the same as zlib).  They are providing an _alternative_ to zlib as well, their own proprietary LZFSE format that provides comparable compression ratios to zlib but 2 to 3 times faster compression and decompression.

Answer (score 3):

"zipped up" implies the .zip format, which is not the same as saying it has been compressed with deflate.  The .zip format is an archive wrapper around compressed data formats that permits the compression and storage of files and directory structures, along with attributes, in a single .zip file.  The compressed data formats *include* deflate (which is the most commmon).

So your deflate compressed data is likely not wrapped in the .zip file format.

Deflate compressed data can be found wrapped in gzip (.gz) files, PDF files, PNG files, and other formats.

In any case, you can use zlib to decompress the raw deflate format, however it may be wrapped, or not, in your data.  zlib is already present in OS X and iOS as a shared library.  As noted by @MirekE, you can access it from the new [Compression Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression).

Answer (score 2):

Clean Swift 3 wrapper around Apples new libcompression:
https://github.com/mw99/SwiftDataCompression

Usage example:

```
let s = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ_0123456789"
var res: Data? = s.data(using: .utf8)

res = res?.deflate()
res = res?.inflate()

res = res?.zip()
res = res?.unzip()

res = res?.compress(withAlgorithm: .LZFSE)
res = res?.decompress(withAlgorithm: .LZFSE)

res = res?.compress(withAlgorithm: .LZ4)
res = res?.decompress(withAlgorithm: .LZ4)

res = res?.compress(withAlgorithm: .LZMA)
res = res?.decompress(withAlgorithm: .LZMA)

res = res?.compress(withAlgorithm: .ZLIB)
res = res?.decompress(withAlgorithm: .ZLIB)

assert(res != nil)
let t = String(data: res!, encoding: .utf8)
assert(s == t)
```

Trying this in the playground is quite interesting because by changing the input string you can see immediately see the compression ratio.

Comment: This is link only answer. Add details