# Socket.IO error: zlib no such module (Swift 3, Xcode 8.3)

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io, zlib

I followed the instructions of Socket.IO's `README.md` of manually implementing Socket.IO. I dragged in the Source folder into my project and I double-checked to make sure 'Add to target' was selected. When I try to run my project, I get an error 'No such module' because `zlib` can't be found in `Compression.swift`. Am I supposed to add any other files or folder to my project? What am I missing here?

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi That doesn't even remotely answer my question. What am I supposed to do with that? The question has nothing to do with `zlib` or `Socket.IO` and the answers reference to some sort of framework or package that I know absolutely nothing about. Totally different problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Native Swift implementation of DEFLATE (unzip) algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953852/native-swift-implementation-of-deflate-unzip-algorithm)

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko Will you knock it off with your annoying "Possible duplicate" comments?! I already told the guy above here it's NOT a duplicate. You literally posted the exact same link he posted. That's a totally different question!

Comment: Also check this answer [about integrating zilb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648121/native-zlib-inflate-deflate-for-swift3-on-ios)

Comment: Also check this answer [about integrating zilb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648121/native-zlib-inflate-deflate-for-swift3-on-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to find the answer on my own, even though the documentation of Socket.IO is very unclear about this and doesn't mention anything about `zlib`. To import `zlib`, go to your project's Build Settings and scroll to Swift Compiler - Search Paths. There, you should create a new path by clicking the + in both Release and Debug. Then, add the folder path to the `zlib` folder that was included in the Github file you downloaded. You can either direct your folder path to its original location inside the Github folder you downloaded, or you can place the `zlib` folder inside your project folder. It doesn't matter where you leave the folder, as long as you're referring to it correctly. Now, build and run and the `No such module` error should disappear.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I copied the zlib folder to my project folder, but my problem persists. How did you reference the library correctly?

Comment: Also check this answer about integrating zilb   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648121/native-zlib-inflate-deflate-for-swift3-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when compiling the project after having added `socket.io`. I fixed it by adding `libz.tbd` to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries (clicked the + button in the General tab of the target, then I picked it from the list).

After doing that however, I got another error:

> No such module 'CZLib'

I'm not sure which version of `socket.io` I added as I copied the entire folder from one of our previous projects. Anyway, the socket folder had a `module.modulemap` file which seemed to define the missing module. So I tried to fix the error by adding the `socket.io` folder containing the module map to the targets `Import Paths`, found in `Build Settings` under `Swift Compiler - Search Paths`.

The project would now compile without errors. At this point I tried to remove the linked `libz.tbd` and it would still compile. I have still not tried to establish a socket connection, but for now I'm moving forward without linking `libz.tbd`.